# PSR Log - Why no NULL default value for LoggerAwareInterface and LoggerAwareTrait

Tags: php, psr-3

According to your sample on [Github](https://github.com/php-fig/log) you inject the logger interface in the constructor with default value of NULL.

```
<?php

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Foo
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        if ($this->logger) {
            $this->logger->info('Doing work');
        }

        // do something useful
    }
}
```

Expressing that something has a Logger you can implement `Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface` and the `Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait`.

Rebuilding the sample code it would look something like this

```
<?php

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;

class Foo implements  LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        if ($this->logger) {
            $this->logger->info('Doing work');
        }

        // do something useful
    }
}
```

Thats fine and working but if i would do this

```
<?php

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;

class Foo implements  LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $this->setLogger(  $logger );
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        if ($this->logger) {
            $this->logger->info('Doing work');
        }

        // do something useful
    }
}
```

it would end up in a `must be an instance of Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, null given` error because there is no NULL default value on the method declaration in the interface. Of course this error can be prevented by guarding with an if or passing a `NullLogger` but this is very weird.

Beeing able to pass an optional Logger instance in the constructor would make me think that i can alter the instance later by setting the Logger to a value of NULL. Of course this is a sample code but lets look at the problem

```
  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null);

  public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger);
```

So basically i can pass a NULL reference into the constructor but i would not be possible to call the setter because NULL is not allowed. It would have been much better if the `Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface` would look like this

```
<?php

namespace Psr\Log;

/**
 * Describes a logger-aware instance.
 */
interface LoggerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * Sets a logger instance on the object.
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger = null);
}
```

So please tell me the background to this decision ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an issue on their Github repo instead of a question on SO? Specially since you start it with: _"According to **your** sample..."_

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/faqs/ says ask questions on SO

Comment: You mean this: _"While there are many user groups and forums dedicated to **providing general PHP support**, the FIG is not one of them..."_? You're question isn't about general PHP support, but rather a very specific question which only the developers can answer (since you ask about the background for a decision they made.)

Comment: Indeed but i thought it would be of interrest for a wider group of people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing many questions here.

The example usage https://github.com/php-fig/log#usage shows how you can use  a `psr/log` implementation in your application. It does it correctly too.

So the next question is about usage of [LoggerAwareInterface](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/4ebe3a8bf773a19edfe0a84b6585ba3d401b724d/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareTrait.php#L24) and `setLogger` method via the [LoggerAwareTrait](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/4ebe3a8bf773a19edfe0a84b6585ba3d401b724d/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareTrait.php#L24)

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
    $this->setLogger($logger);
}
```

If your constructor is accepting null, you should not call the `setLogger` method. The `setLogger` method can only accepts `LoggerInterface` and it doesn't accidentally need to set the logger object to null itself.

Lets say the signature was as `setLogger($logger = null)`. Now if you call `setLogger()` as in example below you can see the logger will be reset to null.

```
$logger = new SomePSR-3Logger();
$foo = new Foo($logger);
$foo->setLogger();
```

If you want to implement a PSR-3 logger you should consider reading :  https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md

Hope that helps.

Thank you.