# How to add logging to an abstract class in php

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

Working on a class library I´d like to add logging to a number of classes. I use `Psr\Log\LoggingInterface` to give the classes access to a logger object. But how do I set the logger in all classes in a decent way. There is a dependency to the logger as it is being used everywhere in the classes

I can use

### Constructor

Add the logger to the constructor with

```php
public function __constructor (
  readonly \Psr\Log\LoggingInterface $logger = new \Psr\Log\NullLoger()
);
```

### Setlogger

Use a public setLogger()

```php
public function setLogger( \Psr\Log\LoggingInterface $logger ): self
{
  $this->logger = $logger;
  return $this;
}
private \Psr\Log\LoggingInterface $logger;
public function __constructor()
{
  ...
  // Make sure a logger is set
  $this->logger = new \Psr\Log\NullLogger();
  ...
}
```

What would be the best way to do this? Is there a better way.

Comment: Create a trait like LoggerAwareTrait and use that were needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PSR Log - Why no NULL default value for LoggerAwareInterface and LoggerAwareTrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401259/psr-log-why-no-null-default-value-for-loggerawareinterface-and-loggerawaretrai)